# Avoiding user access to foreign resources

Tags: spring, spring-security

i m developing a little Spring 3 app and have a problem. In the app an user can publish books, so, obviusly, he and only he can edit these books.
Because i m using rest url, the access to a specific book should be something like this http://bookstoreexample.com/books/published/edit/2(this is not a real url), where 2 is the book, you know.

The problem comes if another malicious user who is not the owner of this resource, realizes that he can write that same url and having access to the book edit. So, my question is, is there  any way predefined in Spring to avoid this?

Comment: This is what spring security acl is for. See also http://hdiv.org/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a database, the easy way to do this would be to modify your query so that it specifically selects and updates books only belonging to the user. So you add something like "Where authorID = " + UID.

Comment: Yes, this is, in fact, my first solution, but i just want to know if Spring Security had a more practical solution to this.